# Is it possible to run single workflow instance for multiple item?

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint Designer 2010 approval workflow and I am starting this workflow on item created. Now when I am adding multiple items it is starting workflow for each item but I want to start only one workflow for all items.

I think this is not possible but I want to make sure.

Is this possible? if yes then how?

Answer (score 4):

Hey I found a workaround to all this coding.

First, set your workflow to run every time a item is changed.

Secondly, add a temporary text type column to the list that you want to run multiple updates on.

Thirdly, in Internet Explorer switch to a datasheet view and make sure to include the new field you just created to the data field view.

Fourthly, go to the first item in your list and enter any string into the new temporary field you just created. Before you commit the changes, highlight the whole column, right click and select fill down. Then change the view back to the standard view (SharePoint will alert you that changes are being made to the list so you should stick around).The workflow will run for all the changes you just made.

All set you have updated multiple items with the results pushed by your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no.  But it would be simple enough to write a small app to do it for you. You can create an event reciever for the library.On that event reciever item added method you can write code to start workflow based on the conditions you want to apply.

You can also check the workarounds :

http://sympmarc.com/2013/01/21/spservices-stories-1-how-to-start-a-workflow-on-multiple-items-in-a-list/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05fafca2-2c5f-48fc-9101-ad8dbdbbaee2/is-it-possible-to-start-a-manual-workflow-on-multiple-entries-in-a-list

Comment: Thanks Aanchal, but I think these examples are for starting workflow manually but I want to start workflow when item is added. Is this possible?

Comment: You can check the option to start he workflow when item is added. But you do not want to run it on every item, If it is manual you can start whenever required.

Comment: right now it is starting when item is added and I cannot change it as it is required. Is there any way that workflow can be stopped as soon as it starts on all items except one.

Comment: You can remove the workflow from UI as well as programmatically.

Comment: This is freaking ridiculous.  I freaking HATE SharePoint.