# Copy multiple selected items from a list to another with a workflow using Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list using sharepoint 2010 and a Custom action button on the ribbon linked with a workflow that copies the selected item to another list. But I need to copy multiple selected items on the second list but when I select two or more items the ribbon button sets disabled. How can I allow that the workflow copies all the selected items?, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only non-code way I've seen this done is to add a column (e.g. Yes/No) to trigger the workflow. Then set the workflow to run when the item is modified, and wait for this column to change. This will mean that this workflow is always running on every item, but without custom code, I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: Hi Erin and thanks for your reply. The problem is that when I select more than one item the Ribbon buttton that starts the workflow sets disabled, what ca I do about it?

Comment: A SharePoint workflow can only run on one item, not on a list. The only thing you can do about it is to write custom .NET code. This question's already been answered... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103592/is-it-possible-to-run-single-workflow-instance-for-multiple-item

Comment: Or SPServices custom code... http://sympmarc.com/2013/01/21/spservices-stories-1-how-to-start-a-workflow-on-multiple-items-in-a-list/. There are other ways to do this if you just google how to run a workflow on multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows work on a single item not multiple. This is why the workflow command greys out when you select more than a single item. You will need to make a change to each item and have the workflow trigger when that item changes or look beyond a simple workflow and cretae/find a feature to do the job.